# Run bash script at login stored in the home folder?

Tags: macos, launchd

When I try to load a LaunchAgent plist from `launchctl` I can't find out how to run a script in the home directory.

My code is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>bash</string>
        <string>~/script.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.tyilo.test</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have tried both with and without bash and also replacing `~` with `$HOME`.
I have also tried using `bash -c` without it working.

The error code is:

```
`com.tyilo.test: bash: ~/script.sh: No such file or directory`
```

Comment: Try putting the full path e.g. /Users/name/script.sh (Also I would make the script executable and with first line #!/bin/bash and run it directly)

Comment: I can't use the full path as it is to be used on multiple accounts and computers.

Comment: If it is to be used my multiple accounts then you should put it in /usr/local/bin/ instead of making multiple copies of it in each user's $HOME. It would be helpful to know what you are trying to accomplish with this script. It sounds like a job for a LoginHook, IMO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`EnableGlobbing` enables tilde and wildcard expansion for `ProgramArguments`:

```
<key>EnableGlobbing</key>
<true/>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>say</string>
    <string>~/*</string>
</array>
```

It doesn't affect `Program` or `WatchPaths`, however tilde expansion works in `WatchPaths` by default.

Comment: This is way better way of doing this. Is there a place where you can view the documentation for the keys in a LaunchAgent plist?

Comment: man launchd.plist. Or see [this blog post](http://nb.nathanamy.org/2012/07/schedule-jobs-using-launchd/) or [my website](http://lri.me/osx.html).

Comment: This helped me too. Tried in the following Mac OS X Versions: 10.7, 10.8, and 10.9.

Comment: Please note: This feature has been removed in Yosemite (`Mac OS X 10.10+`).

Comment: Looks like it's not in 10.9.5 either

Answer (score 18):

***EnableGlobbing*** doesn't work on OS X Yosemite 10.10. It has been deprecated ([ref](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.launchd.devel/56)).

You can see in logs `The EnableGlobbing key is no longer respected. Please remove it.` (from `/var/log/system.log`)

The problem is that `launchd` cwd (current working directory) is `/`, so you can't use `./` like some people said.

To run a script from your home the simple way is to use `(bash|zsh|sh)` `-c`. option. This way you will have the ability to use the tilde `~` or the `$HOME` variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.your.stuff</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <!-- here is the important thing -->
      <string>zsh</string>
      <string>-c</string>
      <string>~/you/script/in/your/home</string>
    </array>

    <!-- code below is just for the example -->
    <!-- Keep running... -->
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true />
    <!-- ...every day. In sec, 60*60*24 = every day -->
    <key>ThrottleInterval</key>
    <integer>86400</integer>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use tilde with `sh`; when Bash is involved as `sh`, it runs in POSIX compatibility mode, which disables many Bash extensions.

Comment: `~/` is gobbling so not supported. You can use `./` instead as long as the daemon is saved in the users home library. (`~/Library/LaunchAgents`)

Answer (score 10):

The most reliable I found of doing this was by using `sh` and the `HOME` enviroment variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>"$HOME/script.sh"</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.tyilo.test</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Note:** the quotes are required.

Comment: This still works in 2022 on a Mac with MacOS Monterey, which is quite great - since I spent at least an hour of different tests to get a .sh-file running via a .plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to know why the script needs to be run from the user's home directory. If you need the user's shortname for the script you can get it by assigning it to a variable as in

```
user=`whoami`
```

Then use `$user` in the script.

I would really put the script somewhere other than a home directory, then it's accessible by other users on the same computer. You could use the Shared directory or put the script in /Library/Scripts/

You will have to use the full path for the launchd plist. Also, in your launchd plist you won't need to specify `<string>bash</string>` as you should have the shebang in the script and it should be executable.

Comment: Specifying `bash` as the actually command to execute is a good fallback with no real detriment. If he doesn't have the shebang, or forgets to make the script executable (o=rwx), then bash will still invoke / execute the script.

Comment: There should already be a variable for the username, such as $USER or $LOGNAME. Also, the usual location for shared Unix scripts would be /usr/local/bin/ (not that you couldn't put them elsewhere, but /usr/local/bin/ will most likely already be in your $PATH).

Comment: Using whoami is just another method for getting at the same info as $USER or $LOGNAME. I suggested the locations above as I didn't want to presume anything of the questioner. Also, before trying to make the launchd plist work, the script actually needs to be able to run from the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Is it executable?

`chmod 700 ~/script.sh`

in Terminal. Also, I would not use $HOME or ~ but rather the actual path to the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.tyilo.test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/script.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

If your script is a user agent (and thus located in the library of the Home folder), `launchd`'s current working directory is the Home folder. UNIX refers to the home directory with a period in the path.

So basically, use `./script.sh` instead of `~/script.sh`. ;-)

Comment: Nope, the working directory of launchd is actually `/`, not '~'.

Comment: @Tyilo I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean "launchd's working directory is the root, in all cases—even in user mode", please provide a reference. If you mean "launchd uses a slash instead of a tilde", read my post again. By the way, I have several scripts scheduled in launchd and they follow the behaviour I describe. ;-)

Comment: @RandyMarch I made a launch agent in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` with the arguments: `sh`, `-c`, `echo $HOME > /Users/Tyilo/launchd_home.txt`. When ran the file `/Users/Tyilo/launchd_home.txt` contained `/`, not `/Users/Tyilo`.