# Why won't my LaunchDaemon start?

Tags: terminal, unix, launchd

I'm attempting to write my first LaunchDaemon: I think it's pretty simple and meets all the requirements, but it won't run.

The file is at `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.noah.supertest.plist`

Ideally, it should be running `ls` and writing the output to `~/test.txt`. But nothing is ever written to the file.

I restarted the machine thinking that might do it, but nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.noah.supertest</string>

  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>ls</string>
    <string>></string>
    <string>~/test.txt</string>
  </array>

  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>

  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>10</integer>


  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>

</dict>
</plist>
```

Permissions are set as root:wheel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run bash script at login stored in the home folder?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/run-bash-script-at-login-stored-in-the-home-folder).

Comment: Interesting, but I removed the ~ and entered the full path with no luck.

Comment: what about adding `<key>EnableGlobbing</key>
<true/>` and `<key>WorkingDirectory<key><string>/path/to/dir</string>` ?

Comment: What are the permissions of the folder?

Comment: @Kent On `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` or `home`?

Comment: On /Library/LaunchDaemons

Comment: Is there a way to get debugging info when it fails?

Comment: @Kent `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: Ok. If that folder is owned by root, then those permissions should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You made several errors:

- It **is** running provided you started the plist properly with launchctl - but it's faulty
- You didn't define a working directory for ls
- You are missing a proper stdout
- You are missing a standard error file (then it's usually easy to detect what's wrong with your agent
- Put it in LaunchAgents instead of LaunchDaemons: ls is **no** daemon

Here is a working plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnableGlobbing</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.noah.supertest</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>ls</string>
        <string>-laO</string>
        <string>/private/tmp</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.noah.supertest.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/user_name/test.txt</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You have to create the file ~/test.txt first before running the launch agent.

Then start the launch agent with `sudo launchctl [subcommand [arguments ...]]` and check the result:

```
...
drwxrwxrwt  8 root      wheel  -       272 Jan 23 12:23 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root      wheel  hidden  204 Apr  9  2015 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 username  wheel  -      6148 Jan 23 12:21 .DS_Store
drwx------  3 root      wheel  -       102 Jan 23 12:07 KSOutOfProcessFetcher.0.sAglCyxY5lzPoNgfmEvv-ZqGl-w=
drwx------  3 username  wheel  -       102 Jan 23 12:05 com.apple.launchd.XFA6PYyYos
drwx------  3 username  wheel  -       102 Jan 23 12:05 com.apple.launchd.pHTdYNvPM9
-rw-r--r--  1 username  wheel  -      1867 Jan 23 12:21 com.noah.supertest.stderr
-rw-r--r--  1 username  wheel  -         0 Jan 23 12:16 com.soma-zone.LaunchControl.dumpstate
total 24
drwxrwxrwt  8 root      wheel  -       272 Jan 23 12:23 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root      wheel  hidden  204 Apr  9  2015 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 username  wheel  -      6148 Jan 23 12:21 .DS_Store
drwx------  3 root      wheel  -       102 Jan 23 12:07 KSOutOfProcessFetcher.0.sAglCyxY5lzPoNgfmEvv-ZqGl-w=
drwx------  3 username  wheel  -       102 Jan 23 12:05 com.apple.launchd.XFA6PYyYos
drwx------  3 username  wheel  -       102 Jan 23 12:05 com.apple.launchd.pHTdYNvPM9
-rw-r--r--  1 username  wheel  -      1867 Jan 23 12:21 com.noah.supertest.stderr
-rw-r--r--  1 username  wheel  -         0 Jan 23 12:16 com.soma-zone.LaunchControl.dumpstate
total 24
drwxrwxrwt  8 root      wheel  -       272 Jan 23 12:23 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root      wheel  hidden  204 Apr  9  2015 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 username  wheel  -      6148 Jan 23 12:21 .DS_Store
drwx------  3 root      wheel  -       102 Jan 23 12:07 KSOutOfProcessFetcher.0.sAglCyxY5lzPoNgfmEvv-ZqGl-w=
drwx------  3 username  wheel  -       102 Jan 23 12:05 com.apple.launchd.XFA6PYyYos
drwx------  3 username  wheel  -       102 Jan 23 12:05 com.apple.launchd.pHTdYNvPM9
-rw-r--r--  1 username  wheel  -      1867 Jan 23 12:21 com.noah.supertest.stderr
-rw-r--r--  1 username  wheel  -         0 Jan 23 12:16 com.soma-zone.LaunchControl.dumpstate
...
```

Comment: Not really sure what this LaunchAgent is suppose to do. I ran `ls -la0 /private/tmp` and output didn't make any sense.

Comment: @nipponese it just was an example. you may specify any other directory

Comment: @nipponese Which directory do you want to supervise with ls? Or what's your plan at all (with `ls`)?

Comment: Just trying to understand how the ProgramArguments works. Eventually, I just want to run an rsync every 10 seconds.

Comment: @nipponese Probably it's better to just call an executable shell script (containing the complete rsync command) with a launch agent then: [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/run-bash-script-at-login-stored-in-the-home-folder).